# Is "look upon them for inspiration" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality, informal-language

The title says it all, but I am repeating it here. Here is the sentence.

> I looked **upon** them for inspiration.

Is this grammatically correct ? Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: The usual preposition here is *to*: "I look **to** them for inspiration".

Comment: Like @StoneyB said, "I look **to** them" means that you get inspiration from them. While "upon" is also technically correct, people wouldn't really say it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prepositions here are tricky and, even as a native English speaker, I don’t see any logic to them.

> “I looked **to** them for inspiration.”

means they were my source of inspiration.

> “I looked **upon** them **as** inspiration.”

means I classified them as inspiration (maybe not for me).

> “I looked **upon** them **for** inspiration.”

is a slightly archaic way of saying that the reason I looked at them (literally, with my eyes) was to get inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Look on/upon someone - Both mean the same! In the example that you have quoted, wrt the context, I would say, **'I looked upon them for inspiration'** simply means that you looked for inspiration in them. When you say, '**I look to them for inspiration'**, it means almost the same. Here, it sounds like When you need inspiration you look to them. The stress is on 'when you need' I could be wrong.

Comment: These are idiomatic expressions with very little logic. The expression “to look **to** X for Y” means to rely on Y as a source for X but does not imply literally looking at X (with your eyes).  You might say for example “I look to the law for protection.” or “She looks to her doctor for medical advice.”  The expression “to look upon X **as** Y” means to classify X as a type of Y for example “I look upon you as my friend.”  The expression “to look upon X **for** Y” has no idiomatic meaning and so defaults to the literal meaning of looking with ones eyes.